# Error when cross compiling Python for ARM

Tags: python, python-3.x, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile Python (version 3.1.3) for ARM, following [this guide](http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html).

These are the commands I am issuing (on Ubuntu 12):

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib ./configure --host --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/python

make HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython HOSTPGEN=./Parser/hostpgen BLDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared" CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes HOSTARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu BUILDARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu

make install HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython BLDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared" CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes prefix=~/Python-2.7.2/_install
```

A few things to notice.

1. When executing the first command, if --host is set to arm-linux, the command won't execute, telling me that I should use '--host' for cross-compiling. This is why I did not set it to anything.
2. When running the second line, I get

> configure: WARNING: Cache variable ac_cv_host contains a newline.
>   Failed to configure _ctypes module
>
> Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules
>   were not found:
>   _curses            _curses_panel      _dbm
>   _gdbm              _hashlib           _sqlite3
>   _ssl               bz2                ossaudiodev      readline           zlib                                To find the necessary bits, look
>   in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
>
> Failed to build these modules:
>   _tkinter

I get a similar error when running the third line, but I guess it's due to the fact that the command above did not work.

I'm trying to  see if anyone can help me fix it.

Comment: What embedded Linux distro are you using? If Python version is not important, you could just take [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It provides Python 3.3.

Comment: I'm doing it as an exercise, CCing for busy-box

Comment: What **ARM** filesystem are you compiling for?  Is it a Linux *glibc* system or a *newlib* [tag:bare-metal] system?  The `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` that comes with Ubuntu will be the former.  Do you have a file system on the ARM device?

Comment: I have busy-box on the ARM system. Does that help?

Comment: Not an expert at this by any means, but the last time I had to do cross-compiling on ARM (for QNX OS) the ./configure step needed to specify --target and --host, I think. Does the --host error go away if you specify --target=arm-linux and --host=arm-linux?

Comment: It seems to me the the ARM compiler is not finding the header files neded to compile those extension modules (_curses, _ssl, bz2, etc). Or the libs couldn't be found... Those are not part of the compiler; so in any case you'll need to either build all those libs from source for ARM (and tell the python build where to find them) or configure python to skip those modules.

Comment: Greggo is correct.  But even if you have those files on the PC (development host), you need the same file on the ARM target; especially for shared libraries.  Python may need all of those dependencies.  Is *busy-box* (bb) all you have?  Instead of shared libraries, *bb* is an executable that includes everything but shares nothing.  If you can find `--without` options, to exclude them, it maybe possible to build.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're missing some **required headers?**  ...not
certain though

Comment: @Bob this might sound naive but may be the **patch** needs to be applied directly after you have unpacked the sources... :/

Comment: If I may suggest backtracking a bit, it is easier to natively compile in a running ARM system than it is to cross compile.  To that end, I like to do ARM software builds in QEMU.  Here is a quick start guide to doing that. http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/

Comment: You should better att tags "C", "C++", "GCC", "Make" and post that on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ I believe you'll find the answer faster there.

Comment: The response to the second command is *not* an error, just a notice for your information.

Comment: You can also use QEMU in user mode a la qemubuilder for a somewhat faster cross-native build environment than using an all-out QEMU system mode setup.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to compile natively under `QEMU` than cross-compile.

Unpack an arm chroot from whichever project you like, e.g. arch linux arm, raspbian, etc.

You already get binary python for arm, but if you really want to compile your own:

Download qemu-user-static (e.g. debian package), unpack that.

Install that single static binary into root of your arm chroot.

Add magic hex to binfmt in proc. Instructions for [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation), [Gentoo](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Crossdev_qemu-static-user-chroot), [genric](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt), [List of magic hex sequences](https://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/embedded/handbook/index.xml?part=1&chap=5&style=printable). Below are my settings:

```
mount -t binfmt_misc none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
echo ':arm:M::\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x28\x00:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff:/qemu-arm-static:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
export QEMU_CPU=arm926
```

Optionally, `mount --bind` /tmp, /proc, /sys, as required.

Enjoy your virtual arm!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and just ignored it and carried on with the procedure suggested by
http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

It worked with a hello_world program. You can also run a testall.py file from the `_install/lib/Python2.7/` folder. 
You can also refer to 
http://whatschrisdoing.com/blog/talks/PyConTalk2012.pdf